# SQL naming a join table

Tags: mysql, join

So I have joined four tables and want to know if I can name the joint tables as one single table. I know it's not represented as an actual table in the database, but almost as a 'virtual' table. I was wondering if you can name this join table.

E.g:

```
Select a.*, x.*
from abc a, xyz x, 
join abc.id = pqr.id AS `joint_table`
```

Is this possible?

Note: I know it doesn't make much sense for you to be able to name a joint table as it's usually used to query records that have foreign keys in other tables. But I'm still curious as to if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap it in parenthesis and then you can alias the subquery and reference it as if it were a table...

```
SELECT joint_table.*
FROM (
    Select a.*, x.*
    from abc a, xyz x, 
    join abc.id = pqr.id
) AS joint_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select joint_table.*
from (
  select a.*, x.*
  from a join x on a.id = x.id
)as join_table;
```